# mysql automatically create 3 records in table when user creates 1 in another table

Tags: mysql

I have a table where user enters records (table1) :
table1

```
id  name    date        desc    amt
1   fred    11/30/2015  Bridge  123
2   fred    11/30/2015  Tunnel  234
```

I need to parse through table1 and create 3 records in table2 (or if the name/date/desc is already there, update the amt field) :
table2

```
id  name    date        desc    sortorder   amt
3   fred    11/30/2015  Bridge  1           123
4   fred    11/30/2015  Bridge  2           123
5   fred    11/30/2015  Bridge  3           123
6   fred    11/30/2015  Tunnel  1           234
7   fred    11/30/2015  Tunnel  2           234
8   fred    11/30/2015  Tunnel  3           234
```

ID in each table is an AI key.  Name and Date are indexed and foreign keys.
What is the most efficient way to do this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would insert the records as:

```
insert into table2(name, date, desc, sortorder amt)
    select t1.name, t1.date, t1.desc, n.n, t1.amt
    from table1 t1 cross join
         (select 1 as n union all select 2 union all select 3) n
    on duplicate key update amt = values(amt);
```

Note:  for the `on duplicate key update` portion to work, you need a unique index on whatever defines a duplicate, perhaps:

```
create unique index unq_table1_4 on table1(name, date, desc, sortorder);
```